# Mostrar acentos en HTML

Tags: html

Estoy llenando una Tabla con información de mi bdd la cual contiene acentos, al abrir la pagina web se sustituyen con el simolo �

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esto sucede en IE11 y Google Chrome

Comment: Hola, tal vez deberías revisar [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base)

Comment: Primero, te invitamos a que leas el contenido del cómo realizar una buena [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), segundo, en ocasiones puede ser por problemas de cotejamiento de la Base de Datos, por lo que tendrías que modificarlo o por medio del Backend filtrar su salida para que muestre el valor correcto. Tercero, tambien puede ocurrir cuando se modifica texto plano desde los archivos del servidor por lo que tiende a mostrar dichos simbolos. Asi que lo mejor es que hagas una pregunta mas acertada y no tan amplia como está formulada tu pregunta.